# Heatmap for iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, heatmap

I have an iPhone application in the AppStore and I would like to analyze it with a heatmap.In another words I would like to know where users touch on the screen when they use my app. I know there are solutions for the websites where you can get a heatmap overlay. Do you know if there is something like this for iPhones? Is it possible? Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can check out: [heatma.ps](https://heatma.ps)